javascript - querySelectorAll with addEventListener - how to get number of interacted element and variable from variable
I have HTML:
<form name="form" ..

<input type="text" name="title1" id="title1" class="f_title" value="smth LV">
<input type="text" name="title2" id="title2" class="f_title" value="smth EN">
<input type="text" name="title3" id="title3" class="f_title" value="smth DE">

<input type="text" name="url1" id="url1" class="f_url" value="smth-lv">
<input type="text" name="url2" id="url2" class="f_url" value="smth-en">
<input type="text" name="url3" id="url3" class="f_url" value="smth-de">

If user changes input "title", i do some replacements with this value and i want to set it to the right input "url".
In a "nice" way I can't get the "number" of interacted field and can't set it to the corresponding "url"... I guess i knew how to do if used for() and eval().
If i use [right] JS things like querySelectorAll and addEventListener:
let i = 1;
document.querySelectorAll('.f_title').forEach(el => {
 el.addEventListener('change', () => {

  if (typeof form.url[i] !== 'undefined') {
    ...
    form.url[i] = form.title[i].value;  // for example - if changes input "title2" - how to alert(2) and how to reference to form.url2 in this loop?
  }

 });
 i++;
});


You can actually create a code snippet with your HTML and JavaScript by clicking the [<>] button in the editor for your question. Just to understand the question: If the value of one of the text input elements (a title) change your would like to update the value for another text input element (a URL) -- just one or all of the URLs?

You can use the second argument that the forEach callback gets: the index of the title item (either 0, 1 or 2 in your example). If you also query the collection of the url inputs, then you can use that index to access the corresponding url input.
As example, I copy the input value in lowercase with all spaces replaced by hyphens:


const urlInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.f_url');
document.querySelectorAll('.f_title').forEach((el, i) => {
 el.addEventListener('input', () => {
  if (urlInputs[i]) {
    urlInputs[i].value = el.value.replaceAll(" ", "-").toLowerCase();
  }
 });
});
<form name="form">

<input type="text" name="title1" id="title1" class="f_title" value="smth LV">
<input type="text" name="title2" id="title2" class="f_title" value="smth EN">
<input type="text" name="title3" id="title3" class="f_title" value="smth DE">

<input type="text" name="url1" id="url1" class="f_url" value="smth-lv">
<input type="text" name="url2" id="url2" class="f_url" value="smth-en">
<input type="text" name="url3" id="url3" class="f_url" value="smth-de">

</form>



